# How to add an IPv6 address and default route with netplan in Ubuntu 17.10 artful?

Tags: networking, 17.10, ipv6, routing

What is the proper way to configure basic IPv6 connectivity in Artful? Basically, what are the netplan equivalents to

```
ip -6 addr add dev eth0 what::ever/64
ip -6 route add default via what::eve0 dev eth0
```

Before, you could just configure it via /etc/network/interfaces but this doesn't seem to be interpreted any more in 17.10.

Answer (score 3):

OK, to augment the netplan configuration you need to add a or edit an existing .yaml file in `/etc/netplan/`. The files are considered in order and the ones with higher numbers override those with lower.

My cloud provider created a default .yaml `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` which I left as is and added a `/etc/netplan/99-static-network.yaml` which augments the provider's config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    yournetworkinterface:
      match:
        macaddress: it:sm:ac:ad:dr:es
      dhcp4: true
      addresses:
        - your:static:ip::v6/64
      gateway6: your:default:ipv6:gateway
```

Then I created the config files from my yamls with `netplan generate` and applied the changes with `netplan apply`.